# subequations: How to continue numbering within subequation?

Tags: equations, numbering, align, amsmath, subequations

Let's assume we want to create one `subequation` including four aligned single equations. The first two single equations should be numbered as `1a` and `1b` while the third and fourth one should continue the numbering of the previous one, but with new equation number as `2a` and `2b`.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number should begin
            4   &=  4
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Questions:**

1. How can I automatically continue numbering of the previous equation numbers without cheating around by manually assigning numbers/tags?
2. Would it be possible to increase the vertical space between the equation 1-pair and the equation 2-pair?

Comment: I have removed my answer :-).

Comment: Should (2)s and (1)s be aligned? I don't think they should.

Comment: Split into two `subequations`.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I am very sorry for this! :-( But thank you very much for your efforts!

Comment: @JouleV: I would prefer if the `=`-symbols would all be aligned below each other for all equations, yes.

Comment: @ferahfeza: I would prefer to align all `=`-symbols below each other for all equations.

Comment: @Dave You don't have to apologize to me at all. Don't worry, I'm happy because my goal is to help. I don't care about the points. My best regards. The comment of ferahfeza is very important.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445115/4427 help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could not find the duplicate, so here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\StepSubequations{
  \stepcounter{parentequation}
  \gdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \StepSubequations
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number should begin
            4   &=  4
        \end{align}
      \end{subequations}

      \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:1}
        a=b
      \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Approved your code. :-)

Comment: Note that in egregs duplicated answer, `\xdef` is used, where I here use `\gdef`, so look out for differences.

Comment: @daleif: I think there is some little issue when using `\documentclass{scrbook}`: In `scrbook` all equation numbers will follow the format `chapternumber.equationnumber`, but your example does not include the `chapternumber` before `equationnumber`. Is there an option to fix that?

Comment: @Dave see if you can guess what to change in the definition of `\StepSubequations`, it is not that hard. Hint, you may want to add `\thechapter` somewhere.

Comment: @daleif: Unfortunately I don't get it. :-( I am very sorry for my bad coding skills. Maybe you can have a look at this one here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482595/subequations-how-to-continue-numbering-within-subequation-while-considering-scr