# subequations: How to continue numbering while considering scrbook numbering scheme?

Tags: equations, numbering, koma-script, scrbook, subequations

The user [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482577/78784) has posted a nice approach on how to increase equation numbers when using `subequations`.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\StepSubequations{
  \stepcounter{parentequation}
  \gdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
}

\begin{document}

First, some normal equation:

\begin{equation}
    content...
\end{equation}

And in following the subequations:

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \StepSubequations
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number should begin
            4   &=  4
        \end{align}
      \end{subequations}

      \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:1}
        a=b
      \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, `scrbook` uses a custom numbering scheme like `chapternumber.equationnumber`. With the counter modification from *daleif* this does not work unfortunately.

Is there an option available to consider the common `scrbook` numbering scheme in `subequations` as well?

In the upper example the subequation numbers should appear like:

`0.2a`, `0.2b`, `0.3a` and `0.3b` to match the numbering scheme of `scrbook`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add \thechapter to the representation:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\StepSubequations{
  \stepcounter{parentequation}
  \gdef\theparentequation{\thechapter.\arabic{parentequation}}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
}

\begin{document}

First, some normal equation:

\begin{equation}
    content...
\end{equation}

And in following the subequations:

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \StepSubequations
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number should begin
            4   &=  4
        \end{align}
      \end{subequations}

      \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:1}
        a=b
      \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a comment to Ulrikes answer,

We can simply copy the normal formatting of the equation number and patch it to use `parentequation`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\sillymacro\theequation % copy definition, then patch, 
 % \ERROR does not exist, so doc will not compile if patch fails
\patchcmd\sillymacro{equation}{parentequation}{\typeout{patched ok}}{\ERROR}

\newcommand\StepSubequations{
  \stepcounter{parentequation}
  % \gdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}
  \gdef\theparentequation{\sillymacro}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
}

\begin{document}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint! But what does this approach improve in detail?

Comment: Say you are using a strange numbering, say it is not a dot as a separator, you do not have to remember how to format this strange formatting. Only requirement is that the copy needs to me made after the initial definition of theequation.