# subequations: Equation numbering does not start with no. 1

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, subequations, alignat

The user [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445115/78784) has posted a nice approach on how to increase equation numbers within `subequations`.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\advanceparent}{%
  \stepcounter{parentequation}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \xdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{alignat}{3}
            \advanceparent
            && 1 & =1 &\quad & (\text{Example text}) \\
            && 2 & =2 &      & (\text{Example text}) \\
            \advanceparent
            && 3 & =3 &      & (\text{Example text}) \\
            && 4 & =4 &      & (\text{Example text})
        \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see in the screenshot, even the very first equation begins with no. 2 instead of no. 1. I have tried to repair this behavior, but I don't get the issue fixed.

How to fix the code so numbering will begin with no. 1 and does continue numbering order of the previous document?

Comment: Well, the `\advanceparent` makes sense only in the middle of `subequations`, not at the very beginning...

Comment: @campa: Yes, I thought the same. But even removing the very first `\advanceparent`-part does not change the numbering scheme.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the possible `\xdef` vs `\gdef` issues @daleif meant in [his answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482577/82917) `:-)`

Comment: @campa: Oh my... :-) Sometimes LaTeX is everything else but not handy. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subequations` environment allows to use `\label` just after it starts, in order to refer to the parent number globally. The idea is exploited in the linked answer.

You don't need this, so you have to explicitly start the business.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\advanceparent}{%
  \stepcounter{parentequation}%
  \startparent
}
\newcommand{\startparent}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \xdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\startparent
1 & =1 &\quad & \text{(Example text)} \\
2 & =2 &      & \text{(Example text)} \\
\advanceparent
3 & =3 &      & \text{(Example text)} \\
4 & =4 &      & \text{(Example text)}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the counter inside of the `subequation` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\advanceparent}{%
  \stepcounter{parentequation}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \xdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \addtocounter{parentequation}{-1}%
        \begin{alignat}{3}
            \advanceparent
            && 1 & =1 &\quad & (\text{Example text}) \\
            && 2 & =2 &      & (\text{Example text}) \\
            \advanceparent
            && 3 & =3 &      & (\text{Example text}) \\
            && 4 & =4 &      & (\text{Example text})
        \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to do that manually at every set of equations, then you can hook it into the environment with `etoolbox`. In the example I have used the begin of `alignat` because the begin of `subequations` is still too early (the counter is setup after that).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{alignat}{\addtocounter{parentequation}{-1}}

\newcommand{\advanceparent}{%
  \stepcounter{parentequation}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \xdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        %\addtocounter{parentequation}{-1}% no longer needed
        \begin{alignat}{3}
            \advanceparent
            && 1 & =1 &\quad & (\text{Example text}) \\
            && 2 & =2 &      & (\text{Example text}) \\
            \advanceparent
            && 3 & =3 &      & (\text{Example text}) \\
            && 4 & =4 &      & (\text{Example text})
        \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```